# How can I create a dynamic range in two directions? I want to use it for a minsif formula

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, offset

How can I create a dynamic range in two directions? Offset only goes one direction. I want to use it for a minsif formula that will start at cell 2 and copy down but only look at 40 cells at a time.

I have this formula in cell 21 and it works great. 
=(MINIFS(AW2:AW41,AU2:AU41,AU21))

It looks 20 cells up and 20 cells down. How can I make this happen by pasting in the formula in cell 2? Basically I would need 
=(MINIFS(AW-20:AW20,AU-20:AU20,AU2))

but obviously I cannot enter in AW-20 as a cell.

I tried to use offset but that only goes in one direction.

=(MINIFS(OFFSET(AW2-20,0),OFFSET(AU2-20,0),AU21))

Not giving me the range I need

Comment: Please provide some sample data with expected outputs. Based on what you described, the MINIFS function in cell `?2` should be looking at ranges from AW1:AW2 given that there is no data prior to AW1 if your data starts from AW1, if it starts from AW2 then the range would just be AW2:AW2.

Comment: This formula works in cell AX21. I need a way to paste this formula in cell AX2 so it will dynamically update the cells all the way down.  

=IFERROR((MINIFS(AW2:AW41,AU2:AU41,AU21)),MINIFS(AW:AW,AU:AU,AU21))

If I try to just copy that formula and paste in it cell AX2 this is what I get:

=IFERROR((MINIFS(#REF!,#REF!,AU2)),MINIFS(AW:AW,AU:AU,AU2))

So I was looking into offset to keep the range of 20 cells above and 20 cells below but it looks like offset only goes one direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
=MINIFS(OFFSET(AW21,-20,0,40,1),OFFSET(AU21,-20,0,40,1),AU21)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! So that's what the parameter height means! It makes sense now! Thank you so much!!! You start -20 cells up and the height is 40 so it looks down 40 cells if I am reading that correctly?

Comment: @movy1313 That's correct. And depending on your requirements, you may want to change 40 to 41 to make the range cover the current row + 20 rows above + 20 rows below.